# SDL: Get window height/width/rect?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

in previously versions of SDL I was able to get the height and width of my problem using the main surface, which had a clip_rect member. Since 2.0 I am using SDL_Renderer & SDL_Window.

How do I get the window size or even better the rect of my current program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the height and width of the window:

```
void SDL_GetWindowSize(SDL_Window* window,int* w,int* h)
```

You can look here for more functions for whatever you want that deals with windows. https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryVideo

Comment: Thanks, already figured it out, but anyway, appreciate your answer :)

Comment: According to the SDL2 documentation, it's better to use `SDL_GetRendererOutputSize` instead of `SDL_GetWindowSize` (see [url=https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GetRendererOutputSize]here[/url]). So
`SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(renderer, &w, &h)` or `SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(SDL_GetRenderer(window), &w, &h)`
seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking for width and height and anything else you'd normally find within an `SDL_Surface` this works just as well, if not better:

**Width:**

```
SDL_GetWindowSurface(m_window)->w;
```

**Height:**

```
SDL_GetWindowSurface(m_window)->h;
```